# Is it possible to merge credible intervals from different Bayesian prediction models into a single estimate?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, credible-interval

#### The situation

Imagine an archaeological site, 10.0m deep. For my study, I construct an "age-profile" for this site, i.e., I produce a model of age as a function of depth. There are various modelling tools to achieve this (eg., OxCal, Bacon, bchron). As I understand it, these procedures model age and depth using Bayesian analysis and MCMC. I am keenly interested in the age of an item found at a depth of 8.0 m. By using each of the three mentioned modelling-tools, I get 3 three different estimates of age at the exact depth of 8.0m. Along with each estimate, I get a 68% credible interval. But I do not have cause to a-priori prefer one model over another.

#### Question

Is there a way to treat this as an ensemble and combine these three different model estimates into a single estimate?

I have thought about just calculating the mean along with the standard error of that mean. But it seems to me that I would lose quite a bit of information about the uncertainty of my age chronometer that is stored in the credible intervals this way. Say for example that all three models produced exactly/nearly the same posterior mean estimate, but with varying (and potentially wide) credible intervals. Using the above, I would then get an error of 0 or close to it. Am I wrong to be dissatisfied with this? In a frequentist setting, I would be tempted to just derive standard errors from the confidence intervals and do error propagation. But I am not sure this is possible with credible intervals.

#### Update 1

Looking through the various tools, I have found in-built ways of extracting actual MCMC samples. And for the tools I could not, these are R-functions that I could somewhat easily modify to output what I want. This opens the door for pooling posterior samples and creating combined credible intervals - but I will have to spend some time checking the validity of a procedure like this (so I will not mark this answered just yet).

Comment: If your analysis could incorporate all the raw data from all of the existing estimation methods that would open you up to a lot of other possibilities.

Comment: @FrankHarrell
Tell me if I am getting warmer! Are you hinting at the MCMC-samples that undergirds each model's credible interval? Because I did consider if it was possible to extract these. Maybe I could then merge equal sized chains, and produce a combined credible interval? Alas, I do not think it is a possibility.

Comment: There are many possibilities, and I’m thinking out loud.  You could put all the raw data into new Bayesian analyses, pool posterior draws from already completed analyses, etc.  The idea of stacking posterior draws comes up also when doing multiple imputation to get multiple completed datasets, each analyzed separately with Bayes, the all posterior draws are stacked which accounts for imputation uncertainties.

Comment: Note the that the very very important and also very very difficult part of this will be knowing the dependency/correlations between the predictions. It's not so hard to combine these results if they are independent...but if you assume they are independent and they are positive correlated (very likely) you will be overstating your confidence when combining under the independence assumption.

Comment: @CliffAB
Hi Cliff - thank you for weighing in. In what sense do you think I should be worried about violating the assumption of independence? So, the input into the various tools are going to be the same. If I throw in a heavy outlier (like the age of Earth at depth = 10.0), all three age-model estimates will explode around 10 m in the same direction. In this sense, the tools are of course dependent and correlate positively with each other. Then there is the sense that how ages are modelled mathematically could be more similar between two of the three tools. So modelistic dependence?

Comment: @BabuR: I'm not familiar enough with how your models + data work, but if the input data to each model is the same, then the outputs are likely to be extremely highly correlated? So you *definitely* don't want to treat the posteriors as independent and combine. In this case, I think you're more in the realm of wanting to do [Bayesian Model Averaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Bayesian_model_averaging)?

Comment: @CliffAB For the record, I am coming around to the reality that you may be correct. So thank you! But out of curiosity, when Marginal posteriors are derived through MCMC sampling, usually several chains are produced in order to assess convergence.  Once it has been deemed that convergence has been reached, I don't think it is uncommon to  merge the various chains and only then produce posterior stats. In a sense, is the exact same thing not happening here? Only, here, besides the data being the same, the underlying models behind each chain are not similar - they are identical.

Comment: No that's different. If you take two MCMC chains that are nearly identical and merge them, your resulting inference will be almost exactly the same (i.e. same mean, same posterior variance). If you combine in a way similar that mef suggested below, note that the final posterior variance shrinks for each additional combined inference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to think about problems of this sort. This approach may or may not be directly applicable to your case, in part depending on whether the assumptions are reasonable for your case.

Suppose you have noisy measurements of the quantity you are interested in. In particular, let
\begin{equation}
\mu_i = x + \varepsilon_i , 
\end{equation}
where $x$ denotes what is being measured, $\mu_i$ denotes the $i$-th measurement, and $\varepsilon_i$ denotes the corresponding error for that measurement. Further suppose the measurement errors are normally distributed:
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_i \sim \textsf{N}(0,\sigma_i^2) ,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_i$ is the standard deviation of the measure error for that measurement. Now additionally suppose the measurement errors are independent. (In some cases these might not be reasonable assumptions, depending on how the measurements were made.)

The measurement information could be supplied as 68% credible intervals of the form $\mu_i \pm \sigma_i$. In this case $\mu_i$ is the center of the interval and $\sigma_i$ is half the length of the interval.

Given this setup, we can express the information available in the measurements as
\begin{equation}
p(x|M) \propto \prod_{i=1}^3 \textsf{N}(\mu_i|x,\sigma_i^2) ,
\end{equation}
where $M$ stands for the three measurements. It's straightforward to show
\begin{equation}
p(x|M) = \textsf{N}(x|m,v) 
\end{equation}
where the variance is
\begin{equation}
v = \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}
\end{equation}
and the mean is
\begin{equation}
m = v \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\mu_i}{\sigma_i^2} . 
\end{equation}

#### Aside

It is convenient to use the *precision* of the measurement errors instead of the variance. Let $\tau_i = 1/\sigma_i^2$ and $\theta = 1/v$. Then
\begin{equation}
p(x|M) = \textsf{N}(x|m,1/\theta) ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\theta = \sum_{i=1}^3 \tau_i 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
m = \frac{1}{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^3 \tau_i\,\mu_i .
\end{equation}
In other words, the overall precision is the sum of the individual precisions and the overall mean is a weighted average of the individual means where the weights are the relative precisions.

Comment: It took me some time to fully appreciate your answer here. And perhaps I might not be ALL the way there yet. I guess part of my problem is that I am not sure of how to extract some of these parameters from a Bayesian credible interval. Take ${\sigma}_i^2$: can I extract this from a 68% credible range between 0.5 and 1.5?

Comment: @BabuR I've added a couple of sentences on how to do that.

Comment: Note that this assumes independence of estimates. If the posteriors are created from correlated signals, this is unlikely to be a reasonable assumption.